# qTip2: positioning the tip, and positioning the corner

Tags: jquery-plugins, qtip2

[image: qtip2 positioning problem]
I'm trying to position qTips under a div, as shown above. The tips are the same width as the container that holds the targets (A, B, C). I'm trying to get the tip to position itself directly below the container, but I want the corner to position itself relative to the target.

**How do I configure qTip2 to get this alignment?**

Target B is straightforward...

```
    position: {
        my: 'top center',
        at: 'bottom center'
    },
    style: {
        width: 350,
        tip: {
            height: 10,
            width: 12
        }
    },
```

but Targets A and C are giving me trouble

If I add some style.tip configs for Target A:

```
    position: {
        my: 'top center',
        at: 'bottom center'
    },
    style: {
        width: 350,
        tip: {
            height: 10,
            width: 12,
            corner: 'top left',
            mimic: 'center'
        }
    },
```

the corner is not positioned under the center of the target... it's off to the left side

If I add a tip.offset, then the corner appears to be offset correctly, but the entire tip is shifted by an equal amount, no longer aligned with the container.

```
    position: {
        my: 'top center',
        at: 'bottom center'
    },
    style: {
        width: 350,
        tip: {
            height: 10,
            width: 12,
            corner: 'top left',
            mimic: 'center',
            offset: 60 // about half the width of Target A
        }
    },
```

**How do I configure qTip2 to get this tip aligned with the container, and the corner aligned with the target?**

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved it:

**for Target A**

```
position: {
    my: 'top center',
    at: 'bottom center'
},
style: {
    width: 350,
    tip: {
        height: 10,
        width: 12,
        offset: -120 // offset from the center
    }
},
```

**for Target B**

```
position: {
    my: 'top center',
    at: 'bottom center'
},
style: {
    width: 350,
    tip: {
        height: 10,
        width: 12,
        offset: 120 // offset from the center
    }
},
```